# Matching two names in same column in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new to coding in R and was finding trouble matching two names in the same column.

To be more specific I have a table of multiples rows with a column called "fileName" that gives the name of persay different colors. This table was combined from two different tables so the first table's color names are called new_red and the second is referred to as old_red for example.

I want to be able to make a new column that says that if the set of characters match multiple times in the fileName column, then in the new column to write "Match" for the row that the color is placed in. If the new_ is a unique color where there is no old_ with that color, to write "No_new_match" and the same for the old where it would write "No_old_match".

I believe there is a line of code that references a certain number of numbers/characters after a name i.e it would look for 3 characters for new_xxx. I tried doing it that way where it was like "new\d{3}" but it didn't work the way I intended to.

Here is an example of what I am referring to

**fileName**

1. new_red
2. new-blue
3. new_green
4. old_red
5. old_purple

---

1. Match
2. No_new_match
3. No_new_match
4. Match
5. No-old_match

   Any help would be appreciated, I new how to create a new column and such for the table I want to make but I am having trouble with this part. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with `dplyr` -

```
df <- data.frame(fileName = c("new_red", "new_blue", "new_green", "old_red", "old_purple"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

df %>%
  mutate(
    Match = sapply(strsplit(fileName, "_"), "[", 2),
    Match = duplicated(Match) | duplicated(Match, fromLast = T)
  )

    fileName Match
1    new_red  TRUE
2   new_blue FALSE
3  new_green FALSE
4    old_red  TRUE
5 old_purple FALSE
```

You can make cosmetic changes to the `Match` column as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using regular expressions:

```
fileName <- c("new_red", "new_blue", "new_green", "old_red", "old_purple")
color <- gsub("(new_)|(old_)", "", fileName)
color.freq <- table(color)

df <- data.frame(
  fileName = fileName,
  color = color,
  match = ifelse(
    color.freq[color] == 2,
    "Match",
    ifelse(
      grepl("new", fileName),
      "No_new_match",
      "No_old_match"
    )
  )
)

    fileName  color        match
1    new_red    red        Match
2   new_blue   blue No_new_match
3  new_green  green No_new_match
4    old_red    red        Match
5 old_purple purple No_old_match
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this really worked with my data. I appreciate  the help!